MPU protected region not protected against EEFC_FCR ES erasure (cortex m4)
I set up an MPU region on a Cortex-M4 with AP encoding 000 (no access),
MPU->RBAR = address | (1 << 4) | (1 << 0);
MPU->RASR = (1 << 17) | (1 << 3) | (1 << 0);
MPU->CTRL = 0b111;
SCB->SHCSR |= (1 << 16);

and do indeed get a fault if I try to write to this region from the background region.
However, erasing the region using the ES command in the EEFC_FCR register executes without any problems. Does the MPU not protect against flash controller erase operations?

MPU is protecting the "regular" memory space. That is, it performs checks of individual memory transactions against the rules configured (access type, priviledge level etc). It is not a physical medium protection and has no role when a hardware controller is manipulating the underlying hardware memory device.

This is like a DMA attack.  An MMU (and MPU) do not protect against hardware.  This is the fundamental difference between MMU OS protection and TrustZone based systems. [tag:trustzone]  You also need physical protection against bus jamming attacks.  The MMU and MPU are to prevent unintended errors from disabling a system.  You need to trust (and limit) access to a flash controller.  If this was safety based, that code needs to be to a higher standard.  If this is security based, then you may have other considerations.

Cortex-M4 does not define a flash controller, that will be manufacturer dependent.  EEFC_FCR is specific to Microchip/Atmel AT-SAM devices and is not a Cortex-M4 register.
Flash erase for on-chip flash is not a memory mapped operation.  It is managed by the flash controller directly, independent of the CPU and MPU.
For on-chip flash, write protection is normally managed through the MCU's flash controller.  The EEFC has at least two forms of protection:

Lock bits that provide erase/write protection of "lock regions", a lock region is a block of 8Kbytes, (for SAM4S devices - check your datasheet for other devices) the number of lock bits is determined by the total flash size.
Security Bit - that blocks read. write and erase operations on the entire flash.

Some parts (you were not specific) have an additional protection mechanism:

Register Write Protection - blocks write access to EEFC registers, this indirectly preventing flash erase and write operations.

